# R shinyapps won't deploy: "Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

The app runs fine locally. It uses a series of sliders to form a reactive i.e.

```
block_data <<- reactive({blocks %>% 
            filter(pred_percentile >= input$pred_slider[1] & pred_percentile <= input$pred_slider[2] 
                   & crime_percentile >= input$crime_slider[1] & crime_percentile <= input$crime_slider[2]
                   & housing_percentile >= input$housing_slider[1] & housing_percentile <= input$housing_slider[2]
                   & traffic_percentile >= input$traffic_slider[1] & traffic_percentile <= input$traffic_slider[2]
            )
})
```

Anyone run into this issue before? Again, works fine locally, and then I receive the error message immediately when trying to deploy.

Comment: This error means that you're trying to access a value out of boundary, such as : `a <- 1:10`, then you're asking for a[11] which doesnt exist as you have only 10 variables. I suspect one of your variables may be `null`. Try to use `req()` and please try not to use global assignment operator like that. take it out of the `server.R` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much. By printing all variables shows that none of them are null, so that is likely not the problem. All of my event observers include `req()`. Any other possible reasons for this that you're aware of?

Comment: I would need to see more code of the app so I can reproduce it

Comment: In the end there was something wrong with my `rsconnect`. Deleting and regenerating the file solved the issue. Thanks again for taking a shot at this.